# Is it possible to have one date field in a sharepoint 2010 calendar?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-calendar

I'm trying to make a due date calendar and have it only use one date instead of a start and end date.  Is there any way to do that?  I also want this to be in a calendar view and not a list view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in that case you might want to start from a task list and customize it out with the fields you need. This gives you the due date you need and you can create calendar views on top of it too.